# WPF - Align checkbox with datagrid column

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to position a checkbox above a column in a datagrid, and keep the checkbox aligned with the left edge of the column, even if the columns are resized (or reordered) by the user.

[image]

Putting the checkbox in the column header is probably not an option.
The first challenge is knowing when the user is resizing a column.
There is a ColumnHeaderDragStarted event, but I think that is raised when the user drags a column header to reorder it.  Does it also apply to a column resize operation?

The next challenge is re-positioning  the checkbox as the column is moved.  How can the position of the left edge of the column ("Val1", for example) be determined w/r/t to the left edge of the containing grid?  I suspect that if that value can be determined, it can be used to position the checkbox.

Thanks for any insights in to this problem --

**UPDATE 2**
This xaml is providing much of the desired behavior, but the alignment isn't right.  If the user move the separator between "Id" and "Val1", the checkbox moves.
The goal, however, is to have the checkbox remain aligned above "Id"; it should move only when the separator between "Name" and "Id" is moved.

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  />

    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <CheckBox Content="Check One" 
            Canvas.Top="10" 
            Canvas.Left="{Binding Columns[1].ActualWidth, ElementName=DataGrid}" />
    </Canvas
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE**:
This seems like it might be a useful approach: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094009/107037
The challenge of positioning the checkbox still exists, however...

Since someone asked:

```
Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="32" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<CheckBox Content="Check One" Grid.Column="1" />
<CheckBox Content="Check One" Grid.Column="2" />

<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please post your xaml

Comment: I suspect I'll have to use a Canvas to be able to use absolute positions with the checkboxes w/r/t to columns.

Comment: @Number8 Why don't you want to put the checkbox into header?

Comment: @Sham It would increase the height of the header row, adding a lot of useless whitespace to the grid.  I don't think the customer will accept that.

Comment: @Number8 No, it will not add any space if you keep them align horizontally not vertically with header text. The UI solution you are talking about would be difficult to develop and may be error prone.